# Testing Flask-Wtform DateTime Field

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to use the flask test client to `'PUT'` data but for some reason the Wtform's date field is giving `'Not a valid datetime value error'`

The `format` field is set to `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` and in the `raw_data` field I can see that I am receiving the correct format for example `['2020-04-25T17:55:36']` so it seems it should be parsed correctly

Here is the test client code

```
client.put(
            "test/datefield",
            data = {
                "date" : datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the example which worked

```
from datetime import datetime
client.put(
            "test/datefield",
            data = {
                "date" : datetime(2020, 4, 26, 14, 0),
            }
        )
```